# How to handle the back button pressed event in a fragment?

Tags: android-fragments

I am a newbie in android. I am currently working on an app with navigation drawer having many fragments. So i am trying to capture back button pressed event by using following code for going to the home page.

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment = new ProgressGraph();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

but the event of back button is not getting triggered..
Please help/guide me to solve this problem.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can override onBackPressed() method in activity, which contains your fragments.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't allow me to override onBackPressed() method :'(

Comment: Other solution is to override onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) and then handle KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK.